# How to install the locate command on nixos

Tags: nix, nixos

I've searched on the [nixos package manager](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.11&from=0&size=50&buckets=%7B%22package_attr_set%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22package_license_set%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22package_maintainers_set%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22package_platforms%22%3A%5B%5D%7D&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=locate), if there is package named locate.
Yes and several. But that's not the bash command that I am searching for.

I want to add this bash command

```
locate name.extention
```

which gave me the path of this file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `mlocate` provides a `locate` executable.  The package `plocate` provides an executable named `plocate` which might be better.  Both of these packages will require some extra setup steps to allow them to build their file location database, and I don't happen to have a link to those instructions at the moment.

```
nix-shell -p mlocate
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I m curious to know how you have it

Comment: I clicked on the link in your question and saw `mlocate` there, and tried it out.